# Would finding a Merkle-Damgård preimage that doesn't change the initial state allow an attacker to prepend it to any hashed message?

Tags: hash, sha-1, md5, preimage-resistance, merkle-damgaard

Suppose, a message M was found so that MD5(M) = S, where S is the initial state of the MD5 function (0x01234567, ...).

Given a hash MD5(m), would this allow computing MD5(M∥m∥padding), where padding is an empty block to get the length right?

Comment: I changed the title to fix the misspelling of Damgård. An å is not the same as an a at all. If you can't type å with your keyboard, use the alternative spelling aa instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite. But it *would* allow computing ${\rm MD5}(M \,\|\, {\rm pad}_M \,\|\, m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m \,\|\, {\rm whatever})$, where ${\rm pad}_M$ and ${\rm pad}_m$ are the extra length padding bytes appended to $M$ and $m$ respectively by the MD5 algorithm, as described in [RFC 1321 sections 3.1 and 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321#section-3.1).

---

To see why, it's worth looking at how the MD5 hash (like other similar hash functions based on the Merkle–Damgård construction) works.  Specifically, MD5 consists of a compression function $f: \{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^b \to \{0,1\}^n$ (where, for MD5, $n = 128$ and $b = 512$), a fixed $n$-bit initial state vector $IV \in \{0,1\}^n$ and a padding scheme for extending an arbitrary input string to a multiple of $b$ bits (and also encoding its length into the padding).

For our purposes, it turns out to be useful to also define the iterated compression function $f^*$ that takes an $n$-bit IV $s_0$ and a sequence of $b$-bit input blocks $(m_1, m_2, m_3, \dots, m_k)$ as input, and returns the $n$-bit output $s_k$, where $s_i = f(s_{i-1}, m_i)$ for $1 \le i \le k$.  Then, for any given input message $m$, we have $${\rm MD5}(m) = f^*(IV, m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m).$$

In particular, the usual MD5 length extension attack lets us, given $H_m = {\rm MD5}(m)$ and the length of some unknown message $m$, compute ${\rm MD5}(m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m \,\|\, x)$ for any arbitrary suffix $x$ as $f^*(H_m, x \,\|\, {\rm pad}'_x)$, where the modified padding ${\rm pad}'_x$ is the same as the normal MD5 padding for the message $x$, except that the input length encoded in the padding is increased by the length of the prefix $m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m$.

Now, in your scenario, we have a special message $M$ such that $${\rm MD5}(M) = f^*(IV, M \,\|\, {\rm pad}_M) = IV.$$  Thus, by the construction of the iterated compression function $f^*$, we also know that $$f^*(IV, M \,\|\, {\rm pad}_M \,\|\, m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m) = f^*(IV, m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m) = {\rm MD5}(m).$$

Thus, given ${\rm MD5}(m)$ and the lengths of $M$ and $m$, we can compute ${\rm MD5}(M \,\|\, {\rm pad}_M \,\|\, m \,\|\, {\rm pad}_m \,\|\, x)$ as $f^*({\rm MD5}(m), x \,\|\, {\rm pad}''_x)$, where the modified padding ${\rm pad}''_x$ now encodes the combined length of $M$, ${\rm pad}_M$, $m$, ${\rm pad}_m$ and $x$.